# Print data from mysql database into php

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to pull all the trackName out of mysql. When running the script in mysql it work perfectly. Also if I change the .$info['trackName'] to " Example Trank " that work fine too

So my question is why won't it print the tracks pulled from the database?

Below is the code I am using:

```
<?php

$data = mysql_query(" SELECT li.leagueID,   li.seasonID ,   li.championshipID,   li.userID , li.trackID, tr.trackName
                      FROM leagueinformation li
                      INNER JOIN tracks tr ON tr.trackID = li.trackID
                      WHERE leagueID = 1 AND seasonID = 1 AND championshipID = 1 AND userID = 1 ") or die(mysql_error());

                      $trackNumber = 1;

                      while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {

                        echo "<div class=\"span2\">\n";
                          echo " <h5> Track " . $trackNumber . " :"  . "</h5><span>" . $info['tr.trackName'] . "</span>\n";
                        echo " </div>\n";

                      $trackNumber++;

                    }

                  ?>
```

Comment: maybe `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`? also, just fyi, but `mysql_` calls are deprecated. you should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: What about `$info['trackName']`

Comment: Try using print_r instead of echo.

Comment: What good would that do @coronator1999?

Comment: @putvande: It will show the OP what the variable `$info` _actually_ contains …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Are your tables called "leagueinformation" and "tracks" or "li" and "tr"?
- Specify your table names in your WHERE clause
- You're using a JOIN but only SELECTing from one table
- Check to see that you're actually getting results from the DB.
- Unnecessary concatenation

Try something like this:

```
$query =    "SELECT 
                li.leagueID,   
                li.seasonID ,   
                li.championshipID,   
                li.userID , 
                li.trackID, 
                tr.trackName
            FROM 
                li
            INNER JOIN 
                tr 
            ON 
                tr.trackID = li.trackID
            WHERE 
                li.leagueID = 1 AND 
                li.seasonID = 1 AND 
                li.championshipID = 1 AND 
                li.userID = 1 ";

$data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($data) < 1){
    die("No rows found");
}

$trackNumber = 1;

while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){

    echo "<div class=\"span2\">\n";
    echo " <h5> Track " . $trackNumber . " : </h5><span>" . $info['trackName'] . "</span>\n";
    echo " </div>\n";

    $trackNumber++;

}
```

Comment: Also, irrelevant to your question, but echo is a little faster if you use commas instead of periods.

Comment: Also, it would be `$info['trackName']`, not `$info['tr.trackName']`

Answer (score 0):

Look like a syntax error but i can't find it,
you should use the var_dump() function in your $info variable to get the exact syntax of your array key like this.

sorry i have a issues i can't past all the code just put  var_dump($info); in you loop
Hope it's helpfull

regards

Comment: It had better be a comment.